# Failed to render template <Template memory:7f71d4d57a90> Odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to send email to manager group in pos, and added it in the chatter. So, I added a template, and added code to send email in the python function. But, I got the following error:

```
Failed to render template <Template memory:7f71d4d57a90> using values {'format_date': <function MailTemplate._render_template.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f71d6146c80>, 'format_datetime': <function MailTemplate._render_template.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f71d6146e18>, 'format_amount': <function MailTemplate._render_template.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f71d6146f28>, 'format_duration': <function MailTemplate._render_template.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f71d6146ea0>, 'user': res.users(2,), 'ctx': {'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 2, 'allowed_company_ids': [1], 'active_model': 'pos.config', 'active_id': 1, 'active_ids': [1], 'safe': False}, 'object': pos.session(3,)}  
UndefinedError: 'odoo.api.pos.session object' has no attribute 'user'
```

***Python code:***

```
class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'
    def _warning_balance_closing(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        context = dict(self._context)
        context['session_id'] = self.id
        template_id = self.env.ref('my_module.email_template')
        managers = self.env.ref('point_of_sale.group_pos_manager')
        users = managers.users
        users = list(set(users))
        if template_id:
            for user in users:
                template_id.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True,
                                      email_values={'email_to': user.email})

        return {
            'name': _('Balance control'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'closing.balance.confirm.wizard',
            'views': [(False, 'form')],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'context': context,
            'target': 'new'
        }
```

***Template:***

```
 <record id="email_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Template e-mail</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(user.email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">Template e-mail</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_pos_session"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="body_html">
                <![CDATA[
              <p>Dear ${object.user.name or ''},
                Regards,
              </p>
        ]]>
            </field>
        </record>
```

What's wrong in my code ? Any help please ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got an:

```
UndefinedError: 'odoo.api.pos.session object' has no attribute 'user'
```

To get the username use `user_id` instead.

***Example:***

```
object.user_id.name
```

Comment: I'm using send_mail function , how can I got the mail displayed on chatter ? any help please?

Comment: Try to use `record.message_post(body=)`

Comment: I need email_values={'email_to': user.email}  and template_id , can I got it with message_post?

Comment: You can check the [message_post](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py#L1797) source code documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to import the model in your *init*_.py

Comment: I imported it in in the __init_.py

Comment: can you provide us with your init.py code

Comment: from . import models

Comment: the issue was solved when I removed the line             <field name="email_from">${(user.email or '')|safe}</field> from template